# Find out details of the script associated with PID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, pid

By using the `top` command, I can see the processes running on my server:

[image]

I have noticed that R and postgres are always using a considerable amount of CPU.

How does one reveal the actual query or script that is associated with the PID taking up so much CPU?  What command should one use in the terminal?

Comment: Use database administrator utilities related to those applications.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.